# When to Redis? When to Tarantool?

Tags: database, redis, nosql, in-memory, tarantool

I do not want to get a detailed comparison. Neither do I want to define 'what is the best or fastest' in-memory DB.

They are both similar, so I want to get an overview of critical differences.

So what are they?

Answer (score 8):

Let me be the one to offer a solution to the question above, I did a little research. From my point of view, these are the most critical things to know about them.

**Overall**

- both are extremely fast in-memory technologies
- open-source and Enterprise versions
- store all the data in-memory
- offer RPS of 10 000 and greater
- Persistence: they both snapshot data to disk
- Support async replication
- Redis is a key-value storage
- Tarantool supports key-value, but also supports documents and relational model

**Why Redis is preferable**

- easier to get started
- more Information on the Internet (look ant the number of question here, for example)
- a simplier technology overall
- more people are familiar with it

**Why Tarantool is preferable**

- supports secondary indexes
- supports iteration over indexes
- has a UI for cluster administration
- has an app-server onboard by default

**Conclusion**

- Redis is a great caching solution. Not recommended to use it as a main storage
- Tarantool is a multi parading DB. Can be used as a main storage
- Redis has a lower entry barrier
- Tarantool has a higher ceiling as a solution (relational model, distributed NoSQL storage, queues)